# Alternatives to Boxee

Tags: macos, media-center, netflix, hulu

I have a mac mini that I'm using as a media hub.  After hearing about Boxee I was quite excited.  After installing it, however, I am far less excited.  It's current state is... well... broken.  90% of the functionality I have tried to use simply doesn't work.

Are there any other good alternatives?  It doesn't have to be free, it just has to:

- Run on OSX
- Play internet content (e.g. hulu, south park, etc)
- Play Netflix
- Interface with an external remote.  I have an Apple remote (why I bought that I don't know) and an iPod, and maybe some day an iPad.

Anything else is gravy.  I love Boxee's concept, it's just the execution that drags me down.

Comment: Have you tried [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/)?

Comment: I have not - but since posting this I heard about it and will be checking it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that [Plex](http://www.plexapp.com/) is a better looking XBMC alternative and should fit the bill.